# Regression Model Evalation with unbalanced target; alternative to R-squared?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, metric

The Data look something like this:

[0, ....,  0, 2.8, 10, 4.5,]

So there are a lot of zeros to predict. And just a few non zeroes.

Apllying R2 to a potentially predictive model for this kind of Data is not feaseable:
The difference between all zero prediction and the expected values is not that big.

Is there a R2-like metric to aid this situation ?

Comment: What goes wrong when you use $R^2$ despite your reservations? You’re still seeing how much variability you’re regression accounts for compared to always guessing the mean of the response variable.

Comment: I run my model with simple R^2 , yet the obtained R2  fails to convey an improvement while tuning hyperparameters.

Comment: So your model is doing a poor job of predicting. That’s an issue with your model, not $R^2$.

Comment: that why i want to tune the model into a better predicting model through hyperparameters. But for this, the metric for model evaluation has to convey the right message. R2 failed for me in this case

Comment: Why is $R^2$ failing you by (seemingly correctly) reporting a poor model fit?

Comment: because its getting me a 0.91 with good fits for the zeroes, but bad fits for the non-zeroes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106259/discussion-between-dave-and-alexander-vocaet).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your data are severely unbalanced if they are almost all zeros. Try data balancing or some form of cross-validation. To your original point: there is not a simple R^2 metric fix.

Comment: This is a Model with multiple Targets, each has their non-zero values on different variables. Balancing is only possible in by filtering the prediction. Currently, I will approach this by filtering the none-zero Data. Filling the Amount of none-zero with otherwise similar data, yet 0 in specific target. Thus obtaining a 50/50 balancing for R2 calculation

Comment: It sounds like you're going to invent new data for data balancing, rather than sampling over existing data? That sounds like a spectacularly bad idea. I guess I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: no, sry i did not convey it right. i am not creating new data. I sample some extra Data from samples that are simliar to the ones with the non-zero values.